# Stripping url with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I needed to strip the

```
http://www.
```

from a domain name and also anything following it such as

```
/example
```

so that i would just be left with yourdomain.com

I added the following code to a file:

```
$domain = HTTP_SERVER;
$domain_name = preg_replace('/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/i', '', $domain);
```

But if i echo $domain_name I still get a url such as yourdomain.com/testsite

Can anyone see what i have done wrong here as it has not removed the /testsite and i thought i had got this right.

Comment: So you want only the yourdomain.com ?

Comment: Try: `print_r(parse_url($url));` does that do the trick for you? I think you want the host out of that array right?!

Comment: @lolka_bolka Yes, that is correct

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
$url = 'http://www.example.co.uk/directory/level1/last/page.html'; 
$parse= parse_url($url); 
preg_match ("/\.([^\/]+)/", $parse['host'], $mydomain); 
echo $mydomain[1];
```

Comment: Tried that and whilst it does drop anything after .com it leaves me with www. preceding the url.I must have the domain name alone.

Comment: Nice try, but edit the url to be a .co.uk domain name instead of a .com - Results in .co.uk being echoed.

Comment: @StevePrice try this updated answer it will work for you. I am sure

Comment: That solution works beautifully. Although i had worked out a different solution based on your initial reply and the use of preg_replace, i feel that your final solution is much cleaner so will go with it. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hack that someone will disagree with, but i resolved the problem by using the following code.

```
$url = HTTP_SERVER;
$parse = parse_url($url);
$domain = $parse['host'];
$domain_name = preg_replace('/(?:www\.)?/i', '', $domain);
echo $domain_name;
```

If you can see a reason why this should not be used, please feel free to let me know. Always something new to learn :)